# Postgres: how to declare user type variable?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to write a small script to grant permissions. The script works if I type in the user directly into each query but it's more efficient to use a variable but I cannot find what type to declare it as.

```
DO $$

DECLARE
usr ??? := myuser;

BEGIN

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
TO usr;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public to usr;

END $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   usr text := 'myuser' ;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE '
                  'ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public ' 
                  'TO %I',
                  usr);
END;$$;
```

The second statement works similarly.